# How can I filter datatable values in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatable

I have two checkboxes and I want that when a user checks the first checkbox, hide `include span class = mm--x` in datatable or when a user checks the other checkbox hide `include span class = mm--y` in datatable. Is it possible? Or the other method like include "ss" in rows' Column 5. or 2 select

Here is my code:

```
$("#checkbox1").click(function () {  
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {             
        $(".myTable span." + 'mm--x').hide(); 
    }
});

$("#checkbox2").click(function () { 
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {              
        $(".myTable span." + 'mm--y').hide(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: When adding/editing questions please maintain correct tabbing. This will help you and others.

Comment: yeap you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Your click events have too many closing braces. Remove the `}` on the line prior to `});`:

```
$("#checkbox1").click(function () {  
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))             
        $(".myTable span." + 'mm--x').hide(); 
    // else
    //   $(".myTable span." + 'mm--x').show();
});

$("#checkbox2").click(function () { 
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))             
        $(".myTable span." + 'mm--y').hide(); 
    // else
    //   $(".myTable span." + 'mm--y').show(); 
});
```

**Note:** I originally posted a comment to this effect, after which the code in the question was fixed.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does the binding fail? Do the selectors fail? Does the condition fail?